# Second Species Counterpoint

Tags: theory, species-counterpoint

I am working on a second species counterpoint and I am a bit stuck. This is what I have so far:

[image]

Any tips for where to go from here? The exercise I found online gave me all the notes of the CF and only the first 3 notes of the counterpoint below.

Comment: Just to clarify: the initial "E F# G" of the counterpoint were given, and the following "E D E" were added by you?

Comment: @Aaron yes, correct!

Comment: I've done a possible version of the 8 bars, but I am not able to upload the image.  It keeps saying it is too big.  :(  Sorry - I've not tried to add an image here before.  If it's of any use, I could explain to you what I did, and you could write the notes down Also, I could explain what I did and why.

Comment: @Jomiddnz if you want you could explain it here or email it to me: djdillyc08@gmail.com

Comment: @Jomiddnz it might be easier to email it to me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest sticking point may be the final sixteenth note you have in the opening measure. That last E, if it's intended to be a passing tone within the second-species guideline, is actually impossible to use correctly, because it would necessitate an F♯ on the downbeat of the next measure, which would be a dissonant tritone with the soprano C (and thus not allowed).

Try changing that E to another consonance with the B and see if that helps get you going in the second measure.

Comment: thanks! I changed it to a G which is a third. But then I am repeating a G in the same measure.